# Is it safe to override `receive` in an Akka FSM?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-fsm

I created an FSM with Akka. However, my FSM doesn't only get messages passed that are relevant for its FSM state. Its children may also pass `ActorRef`s up to it, which my FSM should then pass further up to its parent. Since FSMs in Akka are (naturally) also actors, I would like to override `receive` to catch those `ActorRefs`. However, doing that broke the FSM functionality of the actor. What's the proper way to handle a situation like this?

Comment: Just to mention that Akka-FSM has many disadvantages: https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#55-should-not-use-akka-fsm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages that are not relevant for any FSM state can be handled in `whenUnhandled`:

```
whenUnhandled {
  case Event(someActorRef: ActorRef, _) =>
    context.parent ! someActorRef
    stay()
}
```

Though, overriding `receive` should, afaik, work, too.